# How to capture function arguments and store function pointer for later execution in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, function-pointers

My requirement is to store some functions for later execution with pre-defined arguments. Here is what I have tried

```cpp
void doSomething(int i, int j) {
    std::cout << "Sum " <<  i + j << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<std::function<void(int, int)>> functionVector;

    functionVector.push_back(std::bind(doSomething, 1, 2));
    functionVector.push_back(std::bind(doSomething, 4, 2));

    functionVector[0]();
    functionVector[1]();
}
```

However this does not compile and gives following error

```
error: no matching function for call to object of type 'std::__1::__vector_base<std::__1::function<void (int, int)>,
      std::__1::allocator<std::__1::function<void (int, int)> > >::value_type' (aka 'std::__1::function<void (int, int)>')
    functionVector[0]();
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I achieve this in `C++11/14`?

Comment: maybe you have to define `functionVector` as `std::vector<std::function<void()>>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After binding the arguments to the function, the call doesn't take any further arguments anymore. Therefore the function type should be `void()`:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> functionVector;
```

---

Also note that you can use lambdas in C++11 and later, which are more flexible than `std::bind`:

```
functionVector.push_back([](){ doSomething(1, 2); });
functionVector.push_back([](){ doSomething(4, 2); });
```

or slightly simplified, empty parameter lists can be omitted:

```
functionVector.push_back([]{ doSomething(1, 2); });
functionVector.push_back([]{ doSomething(4, 2); });
```

As you can see the lambdas don't have any parameters here and so the type of their call operators is `void()`.

---

Although it won't make any real difference, I would also suggest you to use `emplace_back` (since C++11) instead of `push_back`.

`push_back` expects a reference to the element type (here `std::function<void()>`), but since you are passing it something else, the `std::function<void()>` will first be constructed as a temporary for the `push_back` parameter and then the vector element with be move-constructed from it.

`emplace_back` on the other hand expects the constructor arguments for the vector element and will construct the `std::function<void()>` object directly in-place without intermediate temporary.

---

In this specific instance `std::function` is also unnecessary when using lambdas, since lambdas without capture decay to function pointers, which you can store as a lightweight alternative to `std::function`:

```
std::vector<void(*)()> functionVector;
```

If you intend to store lambdas with capture, then the `std::function` approach is required.